# How to store null values in a triplestore db?

Tags: null, sparql, triplestore

How do I store null values in a triplestore database?

Should I use no triples for null values or use something like rdf:nil ?
If I use no triples, how do I query then for non existing triples?

Comment: Does the related [Modelling an equivalent of database NULL in RDF](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16873174/1281433) question help here?  There are several answers, and I think that question is a bit more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FILTER NOT EXISTS` syntax to check for non-existence

For example assuming you know the subject and predicate and want to check for a null value i.e. non-existence of the relevant triple you could do the following:

```
ASK WHERE
{
   FILTER NOT EXISTS { <http://subject> <http://predicate> ?value }
}
```